# How to filter for only the lines that all its fields satisfy a regex condition

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to use a condition in awk in a way that filters for lines that all its fields satisfy a regex condition, other than looping through the fields one by one. 
For example, I want the lines that have only (yes or ok) in them

example input:

```
yes yes yes no no ok nok
no yes yes whatever
yes yes ok
ok yes
```

example output:

```
yes yes ok
ok yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your delimiter, let's say it's space or tab, then you can do this:

```
awk '$0~/^((yes|ok)\s+)*(yes|ok)$/{print}' file
```

ps: `\s` is GNU awk's feature, you might need to change it to `[ \t]` for other version.

And the `$0~` and `{print}` parts are actually implicit, we can drop them, simply use this:

```
awk '/^((yes|ok)\s+)*(yes|ok)$/' file
```

Comment: you don't need `$0~` and `{print}`, simply drop them